# Python 3: Deleted everything related to an API I already installed, now that I reinstalled it Python can't find the functions defined in the API

Tags: python, podio

I downloaded the Podio API for Python and after something like ten tries I got it installed, by then I had already downloaded it 3 times from different sources, and when I got errors later (since apparantly I had downloaded and installed the Python 2-version) I was very confused and wanted to simply undo everything and install it correctly without all the crap. I tried uninstalling but it didn't work (partly I think because I don't know which method of installing it was actually successful, it just worked all of a sudden), so I just deleted everything and hoped that would at least disable it. After doing that I installed again it by typing this (relevant since I someone told me the pip-version wasn't updated, but the github-version was, and told me to type this instead. I don't understand the difference since it still says 'pip install') in the CMD:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/podio/podio-py.git#egg=podio-py
```

now I get this error:

```
    from pypodio2 import OAuthClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
  from pypodio2 import OAuthClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'OAuthClient'
```

What causes the problem? Two days of issues with this API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OAuthClient` is accessible via `pypodio2.api`.  Change your import statement to:

```
from pypodio2.api import OAuthClient
client = OAuthClient('api_key', 'api_secret', 'login', 'password')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Finally something works without giving just me a new error hehe.

Comment: If it worked for you, don't forget to accept my answer!